Is there an analogous way to authenticate to `pyodbc.connect('...;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated')` for working with SharePoint/OneDrive?
I am able to connect to my company's Azure Synapse instance using code like the following:
server = 'our server'
database = 'our database'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
authentication = 'ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Authentication='+authentication) as conn:
...

The code runs and authenticates without any popup to sign-in and allows me to query whatever I need. What I am wanting is some way of interacting with Office 365/SharePoint/OneDrive via Python that is similar. I've had other use cases in the past that I've found work arounds with Power Automate or otherwise. My current use case is being able to save emails from Outlook as .msg files. I found two solutions that I think I can combine to do that:
Reading e-mails from Outlook with Python through MAPI
Saving to .msg file in Python, or alternatively, sending mail to the file system
The problem is, when I run the following, it doesn't grab the recent emails. My guess is it's grabbing emails from when I started my computer or Outlook.
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()

for i in range(10):
    next_msg = messages.GetNext()
    if "trigger text" in next_msg.body.lower():
        next_msg.SaveAs(r"my save path", 3)

I'm trying to avoid having to register a web app in Azure because I'm not part of my company's IT org, and they make it basically impossible to get approved. I'm fine with it if it can only run when I'm at my computer and logged in, though it would be nice if it could run regardless. I'm open to a solution via Power Automate, but if I could somehow get a token or some way to authenticate to Azure/O365 via Python, I feel like I could streamline a lot of things I do instead of making a web of Power Automate and other systems to get the job done.
